# Select a node where an attribute contains a text that is of certain length after a certain character

Tags: regex, xpath, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium IDE and can't figure out how to select a given element that has a certain attribute which contains some text (number) of a certain length after a specified character.

In order to better understand what exactly I would like to achieve please see below an example.

I have the following HTML element:

```
<div><h2 class="attribute" onclick="PropertyPopup.Show(63854, 4065)">test test</h2></div>
```

In my case both the numbers in the bracket (63854 and 4065) are changing dynamically and I'm mostly interested in the second number (4065). This can have a length of 4 or 7 so I would need an XPATH (combined with regexp?) that would extract only those elements where this number has a length of 4 for example (like in the above example).

So far I've used the following XPATH:

```
//div[h2[@onclick][string-length(@onclick)<=31]]
```

This is working fine at the moment (since in most cases when the second number has a length of 4, the whole line will have less (or equal) than 31 characters) but if the first number will contain 6 numbers (and the whole line will have 32 characters), the above example will not be selected. If I would put "<=32", then in some cases, it would select those elements where the second number has  a length of 7 (like when the first number has a length of 3 and the second 7).
I've tried to use something like the below:

```
//div[h2[@onclick][contains(@onclick,', \d{4}']]
```

but this will not be recognized as a regexp and will look for an 'onclick' attribute that contain the word ", \d{4}".

Is there anything I could do in order to select the node only based on the second number (its length)?

thank you,
Szabi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
//div[string-length(normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(h2/@onclick,','),')')))=4]
```

Comment: @user2982831 - Excellent! Please consider accepting this answer by clicking the check mark next to it. Thanks!